# How to deepcopy a xml sub element in Python

Tags: python, xml, element, deep-copy

I am very new to XML and Python and putting things together from posts in this site and others. I am trying to deepcopy an element and append to another element using ElementTree. Starting with the input table below:

```
<Company>
    <Identifier>Benesolv</Identifier>
    <Employee>
        <EESSN>111111111</EESSN>
        <Dependent>
            <SSN>222222222</SSN>
        </Dependent>
    </Employee>
</Company>
```

This is the code I have that works, but not how I want it to ultimately.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import copy

tree = ET.parse("file.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

x = copy.deepcopy(root[0])
for elem in tree.findall("Company/Employee/Dependent"):
    elem.append(copy.deepcopy(x))

tree.write("file.xml")
```

Here is the output which copies the `<Identifier>` element and appends to the `<Dependent>` element:

```
<Company>
    <Identifier>Benesolv</Identifier>
    <Employee>
        <EESSN>111111111</EESSN>
        <Dependent>
            <SSN>222222222</SSN>
        <Identifier>Benesolv</Identifier>
    </Dependent>
    </Employee>
</Company>
```

What I want to do is copy the  `<EESSN>`  element and append to the `<Dependent>` element, but I do not know how. I figure that I just replace the `root[0]` with something that will identify the `<EESSN>` element, but everything I've tried isn't working. Thanks for the help.

Desired output:

```
<Company>
    <Identifier>Benesolv</Identifier>
    <Employee>
        <EESSN>111111111</EESSN>
        <Dependent>
            <SSN>222222222</SSN>
        <EESSN>111111111</EESSN>
        </Dependent>
    </Employee>
</Company>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to deepcopy anything; just assign the `EESSN` element to a variable and [append](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.append) it to `Dependent`.

**XML Input**

```xml
<Company>
    <Identifier>Benesolv</Identifier>
    <Employee>
        <EESSN>111111111</EESSN>
        <Dependent>
            <SSN>222222222</SSN>
        </Dependent>
    </Employee>
</Company>
```

**Python Code**

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("input.xml")

for employee in tree.findall("Employee"):
    eessn = employee.find("EESSN")
    for dependent in employee.findall("Dependent"):
        dependent.append(eessn)

tree.write("output.xml")
```

**XML Output**

```xml
<Company>
    <Identifier>Benesolv</Identifier>
    <Employee>
        <EESSN>111111111</EESSN>
        <Dependent>
            <SSN>222222222</SSN>
            <EESSN>111111111</EESSN>
        </Dependent>
    </Employee>
</Company>
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel!! Huge help. I believe this answers everything from my previous post too. Saved me man. Much appreciated.